# Google Script - Pull Date from Form Field and Format

Tags: google-apps-script

I'm trying to finalize a script for a google form that will retitle uploaded files uploaded via the form using data input into the form. I'd like the date to format as yyyy.MM.dd. By default, my date variable outputs the form's date field as yyyy-MM-dd.

I attempted to add a formatted date variable that reformats the date, but then it stops reading the date from the form and instead outputs today's date in the correct yyyy.MM.dd format.

Any tips on how to get the script to format the date in the form's field to yyyy.MM.dd would be much appreciated!

**I have the following -**

```
 var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
 
// returns the total number of form submissions
 var length=form.getResponses().length;
 
 var date=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
 var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(new Date(),'America/Los_Angeles','yyyy.MM.dd');
 var transaction=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[2].getResponse();
 var id=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[7].getResponse();

 var file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
 name = file.getName();
 

 var name = formattedDate + ' - ' + transaction + ' - ' + name.split(' - ')[1]
 file.setName(name);
 
 }
```

**Log for date & formatted date when I add the following & submit a form:**

```
 {  Logger.log(date.toString());
       Logger.log(formattedDate.toString());
     }
```

[image]

**Log for date & formatted date when I add the following & submit a form:**

```
{ Logger.log(date);
   Logger.log(formattedDate);   
 }
```

[image]

**Plus the View > Logs results from running the script within the script editor:**
[image]

Updated date code to

```
var date=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
      date = new Date(date);
  var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'America/Los_Angeles','yyyy.MM.dd');
```

Submitted form with 7/22/1989 date but logs show it registered 7/21/1989 as date and formattedDate and I'm at a loss as to why...
Form -
[image]

Log -
[image]
[image]

FINAL CODE -

```
 var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
     
    // returns the total number of form submissions
     var length=form.getResponses().length;
     
     var date=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
      date = new Date(date);
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'UTC','yyyy.MM.dd');
     var transaction=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[2].getResponse();
     var id=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[7].getResponse();
    
     var file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
     name = file.getName();
     
    
     var name = formattedDate + ' - ' + transaction + ' - ' + name.split(' - ')[1]
     file.setName(name);
     
     }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What I can see in your code is that while using format date-utilities you're using "new Date" that is why it returns today's date you need to supply your date variable.
Try this instead

Edit-1
converted date variable from form response to date using `new Date(date);`

```
 var form=FormApp.getActiveForm();
     
    // returns the total number of form submissions
     var length=form.getResponses().length;
     
     var date=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[1].getResponse();
      date = new Date(date);
var formattedDate = Utilities.formatDate(date,'America/Los_Angeles','yyyy.MM.dd');
     var transaction=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[2].getResponse();
     var id=form.getResponses()[length-1].getItemResponses()[7].getResponse();
    
     var file=DriveApp.getFileById(id);
     name = file.getName();
     
    
     var name = formattedDate + ' - ' + transaction + ' - ' + name.split(' - ')[1]
     file.setName(name);
     
     }
```

Comment: I tried this before posting (should've said) - it just doesn't rename the file at all if I use "date" instead of "new Date" :(

Comment: Oh, i see can you share a log of both variables (date and formattedDate) while executing the code.

Comment: I think I managed to log the items (not sure if there's a way to get more detail - I'm admittedly a novice at these things) - added to original question

Comment: Write Logger.log(date) and Logger.log(formattedDate) to get log and then in your apps script window go to view >> view log (ctrl+enter is the shortcut), also you can see this for more details https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/logger

Comment: Added context on what I logged originally + used Logger.log(date) and Logger.log(formattedDate) and included screenshot of Log from running within Script Editor and when submitting the form itself

Comment: Did a small trial using the result from the form response and updated my answer could you please check and confirm. I am converting the date which seems like being return as a string I hope it will solve the issue.

Comment: So close! For some reason it registered my 7/22/1989 entry as 7/21/1989 for both date and formattedDate (see updated question) and I have no idea why... I could understand maybe the latter if it's misreading timezones, but why the former, which is pulled from the form? Is it a result of "date = new Date(date);"?

Comment: I think it is because of the time zone we are converting the date if I change 'America/Los_Angeles' to 'UTC' which is the default for javascript. it works fine.